# problem with opening .sh file in Ubuntu 13,10

Tags: 13.04, command-line, .sh

I have problems opening a the .sh file for Cytoscape in Ubuntu 13.10. I click on it but it does nothing! When I try to use the terminal it opens but shows lots of codes and does not run.  Sorry if this a silly question I am new to Ubuntu.

Comment: could you please mention the error, means it regarding permission or what.?

Comment: I did follow your insctruction but the answer is

m@m-desktop:~/Desktop$ chmod 700 Cytoscape_3_0_2_unix.sh
m@m-desktop:~/Desktop$ sh Cytoscape_3_0_2_unix.sh
Starting Installer ...
Could not display the GUI. This application needs access to an X Server.
m@m-desktop:~/Desktop$

what is going wrong with this program?

Comment: The best way to add additional information to your question is by editing it, with the *edit* button. It is better visible that way, and comments are mainly for secondary, temporary purposes. Comments are removed under a variety of circumstances. Anything important to your question should be in the question itself.

Answer (score 1):

In terminal type:

```
chmod u+x filename.sh
```

then:

```
./filename.sh
```

The file must have execution permission. (Done with chmod u+x).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, and changing the execute bit was not the answer.  For some reason the shell script says it can not find the X-windows server.  I thought it might be due to Ubuntu using Unity or compiz, but no.

The problem was that OpenJDK doesn't work for whatever reason.  I had uninstalled Oracle Java.  So I downloaded from java.com, installed in `/usr/java/jre1.7.0_55`, symlinked everything in `/usr/java/jre1.7.0_55/bin` to `/usr/local/bin`, and the Cyto installer worked.  It put its run element in the "Other" Application Menu section.

I'm running on a 64-bit platform, so that also may be a contributing issue.

Comment: Please edit your answer to make it more "to the point". One should be able to find the real "answer" part without having to read the complete story.